# Find the line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that passes through the point $(1,2,-3)$ and is parallel to the vector $u=(4,-5,1)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, parametric

Find a vector equation and parametric equation of the line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ that passes through the point $(1,2,-3)$ and is parallel to the vector $u=(4,-5,1)$. Find two points on the line that are different from the point $(1,2,-3)$

Here is what I've done so far:

$(x,y,z)=(x_0,y_0,z_0)+(a,b,c)t 
       =(1,2,-3) + (4,-5,1)t$

$x=1+4t$, $y=2-5t$, $z=-3+t$ (then I don't know how to solve it...should I find "t" first? if yes, how can I solve it)

thanks for helping... :)

Comment: You seem to have found a valid vector equation and a valid parametric equation.  (The object is one dimensional, so you expect one parameter.)  What happens if you set $t=0$ in either of your answers?  What happens if you set $t$ to nonzero values?

Comment: You have correctly extended the principle discussed for your earlier question to three dimensions.  The nice thing about these equation-forms for a line is that they can be taken into any higher (finite-)dimensional space; the "slope-intercept" and "point-slope" forms we learn earlier in math only work in the plane.  As **Eric Towers** indicates, the coordinates for other points on the line are now found by choosing various values of $ \ t \ . $

Answer (score 1):

You don't “solve” this in the way that you compute a unique and well-defined solution. Instead, you *choose* values for parameter $t$ to obtain points on the line. For a given choice of $t$ (which one?) this will be the “forbidden” point $(1,2,-3)$, for all other values it will be a different point. As long as there are no further restrictions than those you quoted, *any* choice except the single forbidden one will lead to a valid point, and any two valid points form a valid answer. So you can choose the values you like best, be it small values, or some such that the resulting points resemble your phone number, or some encoding of the birthday of your loved one, or simply the first two you could think of.